# configured Abp MultiTenancy for subdomains in blazor webassembly Now what?

Tags: subdomain, blazor-webassembly, multi-tenant, abp

I configured Subdomain multitenancy in the client and server of a webassembly app for the client the input url for example is `val = "https://en.api.localhost.com:44367"` I configure it on the client Program.cs like this:

```
string val = await SubDomainTenant.GetApiServerAuthorityWithTenantSubDomain(builder, serviceProvider); // = https://en.api.localhost.com:44367
builder.Services.Configure<AbpRemoteServiceOptions>(async options =>
{
    options.RemoteServices.Default = new RemoteServiceConfiguration(val);
});
```

and in the server:

```
builder.Services.Configure<AbpTenantResolveOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AddDomainTenantResolver(builder.Configuration["App:SelfUrl"]);
});
```

also my configuration on the client is:

```
"App": {
  "SelfUrl": "https://{0}.localhost.com:44367"
},
"RemoteServices": {
  "Default": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://{0}.api.localhost.com:44367"
  }
}
```

and in the server:

```
"RootUrl": "https://{0}.localhost.com:44367",
"App": {
  "SelfUrl": "https://{0}.api.localhost.com:44367",
  "SelfUrlWithoutTenant": "https://api.localhost.com:44367",
  "CorsOrigins": "https://*.localhost.com,http://*.localhost.com:45144,https://*.localhost.com:44367,http://localhost.com:45144,https://localhost.com:44367"
}
```

The application works, But what is the difference with its previous state? I still call my server like:

```
var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("api/account/getkeyiv");
```

and in the server the request begins with:

HttpContext.Request on the server: `https://en.localhost.com:44367/api/account/getkeyiv`

What is the difference with regular requests?

I have this in client Program.cs (the related part):

//`val = "https://en.api.localhost.com:44367"`

```
string val = await SubDomainTenant.GetApiServerAuthorityWithTenantSubDomain(builder, serviceProvider);
builder.Services.Configure<AbpRemoteServiceOptions>(options =>
{
    options.RemoteServices.Default = new RemoteServiceConfiguration(val);
});

var host = builder.Build();

CultureInfo culture;

Settings settings = await host.Services.GetRequiredService<Task<Settings>>();
var tenant = SubDomainTenant.GetTenantName(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
if (tenant != null)
    tenant = tenant.Substring(0, tenant.IndexOf('.'));
if (tenant != null)
{    
    culture = new CultureInfo(tenant);
}
else
{    
    culture = new CultureInfo("en");
    var configUrl = settings.App.SelfUrl;
    var address = configUrl.Replace("{0}", tenant);
    Uri uri1 = new Uri(address);
    navigator.NavigateTo(address, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of the DomainTenantResolver is that it will infer the tenant from the first segment of the URL.

Without this, your tenant/customer would need to go to the login page then use the 'change tenant' option to set their site before logging in, otherwise they would be trying to log into the host (main admin) which presumably they would not have access to. This is not a suitable user experience for production, hence use of the DomainTenantresolver - your customer can simply go to mycustomer.myapp.com - if set up on the server and identity (if tiered) projects as well, it ensures that the requests are tied to that tenant, ensuring the correct segregation of their data. You could also do things like have custom branding on their landing & identity pages, etc.